# PHP cUrl get all integrated variables data

Tags: php, apache, curl, dll, server

I want to loop through all available cUrl integrated commands.

I know that this is not the current syntax but just to clarify so you'll get the idea...

```
$s = curl_init();

foreach (curl_setopt($s, [THIS IS WHAT I AM LOOKING FOR] ) as $q) {
    echo $q . '<br />';
}
```

I'm expecting to get all integrated cUrl commands (for example):

```
CURLOPT_URL
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT
etc...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_defined_constants` return all defined constants

These constants contain curl commands you want!

[php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-constants.php)

get all curl defined variables :

```
$arr = get_defined_constants(true);
$curl_vars = $arr['curl'];
```

and if you want just "CURLOPT_" options, use this:

```
$arr = get_defined_constants(true);
$curl_vars = $arr['curl'];

$array = array_filter(array_keys($curl_vars), function ($k){ 
    return strpos($k, 'CURLOPT_') === 0;
});
```

or you can use foreach to do this:

```
$arr = get_defined_constants(true);
$curl_vars = $arr['curl'];

foreach ($curl_vars as $key => $value) {
    if(strpos($key,'CURLOPT_') === 0){
        echo $key; // here!
    }
}
```

Comment: POW WOW WOW ! A-M-A-Z-I-N-G ANSWER !